# Using Chilkat (DotNet) with Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, chilkat

I what to use Chilkat Components (mainly the SFTP code) as part of an Azure Function.  It all works locally when I test it however when I deploy it I get the following exception.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'ChilkatDotNet46, Version=9.5.0.82, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=eb5fc1fc52ef09bd' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I know that I have installed the prerequisites locally and that is why it works locally, but is it possible to install these as part of an Azure Function deployment?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

A user previously provided this description of a solution:

I got it working by simply adding the x64 version of chilkatDnCore-9_5_0.dll to the project folder and selecting 64 bit runtime in the azure functions configuration